# Find element in a vector with previous and next element equal to 0

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, range-based-loop

I want to go through a given vector of integers and find an integer which the value of the *next* and *previous* integer are 0.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> sample = { 0,3,0 };
    for (int i : sample)
    {
        if (sample[i - 1] == sample[i + 1] == 0)
        {
            cout << "hello";
        }
    }
}
```

However, I keep getting a "vector subscript out of range" error. I think it's because when `i` is 0, `sample[-1]` doesn't exist, same with `i = 2`.

Is there an easy fix for it?

Comment: Did you mean to use an index based loop, such as `for (size_t i = 1; i < sample.size() - 1; ++i)`?

Comment: You're misunderstanding the range-based `for`. `i` is a value of `sample`, not an index. That is, the values of `i` will be `0`, `3`, and `0` respectively, not `0`, `1`, and `2`. However, your suspicion that attempting to access `sample[-1]` is incorrect is well-founded, and when you rewrite the code to use indices you should take care to avoid it.

Comment: Your explanation is wrong. `i` is assigned `0`, `3`, `0`, rather than `0`,`1`,`2`, so using it **as the index** in `sample[i]` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: `i` is not a value from 0 to size-1. It is not an index. `i` is the current value being iterated. The values `i` will have in this case are `0`, `3` then `0`. Additionally, your logic is flawed because it assumes that every element as a preceding and subsequent element. If `i` *was* an index, you would be checking out of bounds indexes when `i` is the first or last index in the vector.

Comment: Ranged for loops unfortunately don't allow you to use access the index of an element; You could use iterators though, but not sure if you've already learned abouth those; otherwise a "standard" for loop looping via the index could work. `if (sample.size() > 2u) { for (auto p1 = sample.begin(), p2 = p1 + 2; p2 != sample.end(); ++p1, ++p2) { if (*p1 == 0 && *p2 == 0) { std::cout << "hello"; } }}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This range based for loop

```
for (int i : sample)
{
    if (sample[i - 1] == sample[i + 1] == 0)
    {
        cout << "hello";
    }
}
```

does not make a sense because there are used values of the vector as indices to the vector.

The range based for loop is not suitable for such a task.

You can use for example the standard algorithm `std::adjacent_find`.

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> v = { 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0 };
    
    auto condition = []( const auto &a, const auto &b )
    {
        return a != 0 && b == 0;
    };
    
    if ( not v.empty() )
    {
        for ( auto current = std::next( std::begin( v ) ), last = std::end( v ); 
          ( current = std::adjacent_find( current, std::end( v ), condition ) ) != last;
          std::advance( current, 2 ) )
        {
            if ( *std::prev( current ) == 0 )
            {
                std::cout << *prev( current ) << ", " 
                          << *current << ", " 
                          << *std::next( current ) << '\n';
            }
        }
    }       
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
0, 1, 0
0, 2, 0
0, 3, 0
```

Answer (score 2):

There's two problems that you run into here.

The first is that using the range-for loop notation, the variable `i` corresponds to the array values 0, 3, and 0. Not their indexes.

The second problem is that, if you iterate from index 0 to the end, you will be checking indexes `-1` and `3`, which are out of bounds of the vector.

Here is code that solves the problem in two ways, the first uses indexes and the second uses iterators. For the second one, you effectively treat `p` as a pointer to the current item in the list. I made the list a little longer to give more cases. It outputs that integers `2` and `5` are surrounded by zeros.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> sample = { 0, 3, 6, 0, 2, 0, 5, 0 };
    for(int i = 1; i < sample.size() - 1; i++){
        if(sample[i-1] == 0 && sample[i+1] == 0)
            cout << "integer " << sample[i] << " surrounded by 0\n";
    }

    for(std::vector<int>::iterator p = sample.begin() + 1; p != sample.end() - 1; p++){
        if(*(p-1) == 0 && *(p+1) == 0)
            cout << "integer " << *p << " surrounded by 0\n";
    }
}
```

For the second example, `std::vector<int>::iterator` is often changed to `auto` to be shorter.

Answer (score 1):

In a [`range-for` loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for), `i` is set to the *value* of each element in the array. It is NOT set to the *index* of each element, as you are currently assuming it does.

You need to use an indexed-based loop instead:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> sample = ...;
    if (sample.size() > 2)
    {
        for (size_t i = 1; i < sample.size()-1; ++i)
        {
            if (sample[i-1] == 0 && sample[i+1] == 0)
            {
                cout << sample[i] << endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Otherwise, use an iterator-based loop instead:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> sample = ...;
    if (sample.size() > 2)
    {
        for (auto iter = sample.begin()+1; iter != sample.end()-1; ++iter)
        {
            if (*(iter-1) == 0 && *(iter+1) == 0)
            {
                cout << *iter << endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `if (sample.size() > 2)`  is not needed in the 1st example.

Comment: @Eugene since the loop requires at least 3 elements in order to work correctly, it makes sense to validate that up front. At the very least, the code does require `if (sample.size() > 0)` or `if (!sample.empty())` to ensure that `sample.size()-1` doesn't overflow, otherwise the code will have *undefined behavior*.